# kde scaling factor

Tags: kde, resolution

I just bought a gpd pocket laptop and I have installed Ubuntu linux on it. I am quite happy with it but kde is having some problems with the scale factor. Basically some windows (ilke the browser) are very small, full-hd without scaling I would say, but some elements (like the bottom bar, or the search bar at the top) are huge. So I can't find a good compromise between them. Image for reference:

[image]

As you can see the bottom bar is very big compare to the font and the size of the browser window. Thus preventing me to increase a bit the scale size.

Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI

Answer (score 0):

There should be a 'hamburger icon' (the horizontal lines in a stack) in the bottom bar that you can right click on. If you can't find that, just try right clicking on the menu bar and open the 'Menu Bar Settings' or something like that (not in front of KDE at the moment).

It pulls up a bottom bar menu. You should see a button titled 'Height' click that button and drag up and down to adjust the menu bar height. All the tray icons should scale to the height you set.

The menu bar height is independent of DIP scale factor. So set that to what you want first, then adjust the bar height to suit.